# Error installing MongoDB PHP Driver: Composer can't find Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

So I'm trying to install the MongoDB driver. After I ran the following command, I get the error messages in the screenshot. Can anyone help me please?

```
php -c /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.8/conf/php.ini composer.phar require mongodb/mongodb
```

[Screenshot of output from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56uUg.png)

Comment: If screen output is text, it may be preferable to copy that text as formatted code block to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are missing the PHP extension for mongodb.

See [php.net mongodb driver](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php)

Comment: I did install it using sudo install pecl mongodb

Comment: Then it is not enabled in your php.ini file.

Comment: I did add extension=mongodb.so in my php.ini file. I don't know why it's not working

Comment: In which php.ini file did you add the line?